# Motorola barcode scanner SDK events C#

Tags: c#, sdk, motorola

I'm developing a software which requires the access of barcode.

I'm using the Motorola SDK, using *C#*.

I have set the scanner as `IBM-HAND-HELD` instead of *HID-keyboard-Emulation*.

But the problem is if I scan the barcode the '`BarcodeEvent`' never fires. Even their source code wont work. But the compiled version of the source code (exe) works fine.

Any idea would help me a lot. I'm using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Are you using the Motorola Symbol SDK or another one?

Comment: Are you debugging the events in Visual Studio?
Did you register BARCODE_EVENTS in Scanner SDK?
Do you have a barcode event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Mode to "USB OPOS Handheld". Then only the events will fire as expected.