# LS2008 USB Barcode Scanner

Tags: c#, hardware, barcode-scanner

I'm working with a Symbol LS2008 Bar code scanner on a Windows 7 X64 machine. The problem that I'm running into is that the that OnBarCodeEvent of the Motorola CoreScanner API is never getting fired. (Even in the sample App provided by Motorola)

My guess is that it is that Windows sees the device as a HID Keyboard and the scan event is getting routed properly to the CoreScanner service. When you scan a bar code, the value does appear in the textbox, however it is not routed through coreScanner for some reason.

I was wondering if anyone has ran into a similar problem and if so, how did they resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the quick start manual for the [Symbol LS2208](https://docs.symbol.com/manuals/7188201d.pdf?userId=37), there are barcodes for setting the scanner mode.  Scan "Set Defaults", then "IBM HAND-HELD USB", re-plug the scanner, and try the sample app again.

That manual is from a slightly later model, substitute your own LS2008 manual if you have it.

See also [CoreScanner (Motorola) Events not being triggered C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520639/corescanner-motorola-events-not-being-triggered-c-sharp)